# Error Flume agent for solr sink by using MorphlineSolrSink

Tags: solr, flume

This is kartheek.Am using flume agent for solr sink and here am using morphlin but am geting following error can you tel me the wat is the reaseon behind this.

error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/morphline/api/MorphlineCompilationException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSink.start(MorphlineSink.java:93)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineCompilationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The error is, as it says, an `NoClassDefFoundError`, which means that it was unable to find the class referenced, `org/kitesdk/morphline/api/MorphlineCompilationException`. I'm guessing that's caused by a bad classpath or if you don't have the kitesdk/morphline base installed. The reason why `MorphlineCompilationException` is thrown is hard to say without know more about your setup, but it indicates an error with the Morphline configuration, probably in `conf/morphline.conf`.